# Why the request exponential growth?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($types_show[0] as $size) {
        echo '<td>'.Form::radio('radio_size', $size->id) '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
```

Here is the a list of radio buttons.
and I use the following ajax code to send the value to php page.

```
$(':radio[name=radio_size]').click(function(){
    var radio_size = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/management/order/edit_input",
        data: {radio_size:radio_size},
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#search_area').append(data);
        },
    });
    });
```

The PHP code return a view page which append to the existing #search_area.
The problem is when I click a radio with id=7 first time ,it send

```
GET http://localhost:8008/management/order/edit_input?radio_id=7&_=1410246332142
```

The second time I click the radio with id=2

```
GET http://localhost:8008/management/order/edit_input?radio_id=2&_=1410246332143
GET http://localhost:8008/management/order/edit_input?radio_id=2&_=1410246332144
```

the third time you can see four.

```
GET http://localhost:8008/management/order/edit_input?radio_id=7&_=1410246332145
GET http://localhost:8008/management/order/edit_input?radio_id=7&_=1410246332146
GET http://localhost:8008/management/order/edit_input?radio_id=7&_=1410246332147
GET http://localhost:8008/management/order/edit_input?radio_id=7&_=1410246332148
```

But I only want to send it once a time.How to fix it? 
Thanks.

Comment: seems you are binding click event every time when request complete.  What response is coming in data?

Answer (score 0):

$(':radio[name=radio_size]') selects all available radios so far. Fix it giving it name/id.